# tinydns only answers a few queries, then logs 0000 / 0000 (query could not be parsed)

Tags: daemontools, tinydns, djbdns

This happens on every restart of tinydns:

```
2023-11-08 13:36:48.528525500 starting tinydns
2023-11-08 13:36:48.532457500 ff9ea461:d90c:3be5 + 001c mydomain.ca
2023-11-08 13:36:48.655592500 ff0c2164:7ed2:a831 + 0001 b.ns.otherdomain.com
2023-11-08 13:36:48.763519500 ff0c2164:67b7:479c + 001c a.ns.otherdomain.com
2023-11-08 13:36:50.370836500 ff1514a6:faea:296a + 0001 differentone.ca
2023-11-08 13:36:50.783076500 ff6ace95:97d5:0000 / 0000 .
2023-11-08 13:36:50.840002500 ff6ace98:2c61:0000 / 0000 .
2023-11-08 13:36:50.874248500 ff6ace49:5c57:0000 / 0000 .
```

And the 0000 / 0000 lines continue for all other queries (days or weeks until restarted).

This might have begun at the same time as upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, that's kernel 5.4.0 to 5.15.0.  I've been running djbdns on various servers since about 2002, in this case on a Ubuntu virtualbox VM.  It is built from djb's 1.05 .tar.gz with nothing but the infamous errno.h change.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.4.  Did you find a work around?

Comment: I tried using the apt package to tinydns and get the same problem.